# lSystem file not found xcode iOS, working on simulator, error on device

Tags: ios, xcode

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My device on 5.1, xcode 4.3.1. and sdk 5.1. My app runs fine on simulator. Gives above error when running on device.

I have tried to put libSystem.dylib from my Simulator.platform path's to my Phone.platfrom path. Compiler ignore as it is not arvm7 architecture. Please Advise or hint what i m missing.